# numpy array dot errors in result

Tags: excel, python-3.x, numpy

my matrix

```
for i in range(1, len(list)+1):
    x0.append(1)
    x1.append(i)
    x2.append(i ** 2)
    x3.append(i ** 3)
xt = np.array([x0, x1, x2, x3])
x = xt.transpose
```

so `x.shape == (301, 4)` and `xt.shape == (4, 301)`
I have an Excel sheet where I'm doing this same operations and the matrix multiplication dot is different

```
xtx = numpy.dot(xt, x)
[[       301      45451    9135651 2065793401]
 [     45451    9135651 2065793401   51334855]
 [   9135651 2065793401   51334855 -560849807]
 [2065793401   51334855 -560849807 -769107945]]
```

where in my Excel using MMULT(matrix1,matrix2) I get:

```
[[       301       45451     9135651     2065793401]
 [     45451     9135651  2065793401    4.98268E+11]
 [   9135651  2065793401 4.98268E+11    1.25189E+14]
 [2065793401 4.98268E+11 1.25189E+14    3.23523E+16]]
```

I know that the Excel sheet is right, and at first maybe Python uses more digits in the float number or something. thing is, the result is way out... and when I tested this with 21 numbers I had no problem. And this difference affects the inverse, which ends up with a negative diagonal and screws over my algorithm.

Is there a different way to operate on bigger matricies? Am I doing something wrong? I found another question where the user asked something similar that happened to him with 4000 long matricies but I did not understand the answer they gave him nor if his answer can really relate to my case.
I have seen similar questions but none of them gave a solution to my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like you are using the wront `dtype` for your numpy array. Please try the following **AFTER your for-loop**:

```
xt = np.array([x0, x1, x2, x3])
xt = xt.astype(float)
x = xt.transpose
xtx = np.dot(xt, x)
```

If this does not solve your problem, replace `xtx = numpy.dot(xt, x)` with

```
xtx = np.matmul(xt, x)
```

Comment: what does that do? i tried it but no improvement was shown, same result.

Comment: It changes the type of the numbers to float64, thus integer overflow is avoided. Could you please post the output of `xt.dtype` before and after `xt = xt.astype(float)`?

Comment: <class 'numpy.ndarray'> in both prints, i printed them with print(type(xt))

Comment: No, that can't be. You typed `type(xt)`, but you need to provide me the information of `xt.dtype`. Or just try my second answer with `np.matmul()` and see if that solves your problem.

Comment: int32 before and after float64
            print(xt.dtype)
            xt.astype(float)
            print(xt.dtype)

Comment: Yeah, that is the problem, just as I expected. So `xt = xt.astype(float)` is the solution.

Comment: I have been in this hole 6 hours! is there a documentation file that i missed? or just experience?

Comment: You are welcome! Some general advice: When doing calculations ALWAYS use float arrays and ONLY use int arrays for indexing! This helps avoiding to run into integer overflows etc. You can take a look into the [numpy documentation on data types](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.types.html). But that is not numpy specific. It is a general rule of data science to use float for data and int for indexing.